# Playing against the 2...c5 systems in the Kings Indian Attack against the French

Tags: opening, french-defense, kings-indian-attack

```
[FEN ""]

1. e4 { Shockingly, I did not play 1.a3} 1... e6 2. d3 c5
```

This can still transpose into the main line with 3...d5. But I played a game with this yesterday, and my opponent played Nc6, d6, g6, Bg7, Nge7, e5, h6, O-O and eventually built up towards playing f5 (not in that order though). I'm assuming that that was theory, since he blitzed it out pretty quickly and got a slight advantage. I’m wondering if anyone knows how to play against it. Does anyone know how play against it?

Comment: Can you post the entire game please? He is playing systematically, much the way that some players play the Colle, or the Stonewall. They can just play their moves without thinking, which is what he is trying here. If you can post the entire game, it might be easier to make a suggestion.

Comment: This is perhaps more a Closed Sicilian than a French (1.e4 c5 2.d3 e6). That plan is quite typical for black against that. I've seen 2.d3 called the "Big Clamp" but it'll usually turn to some form of Closed.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich It is not typically a Closed Sicilian for a true King's Indian Attack player since the Nb1 usually goes to d2. That alone changes the character greatly away from being a Closed Sicillian. The plans are also very different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will try to give a few ideas based on the limited information, and trying to follow some common sense regarding development and the moves your opponent played.

```
    [FEN ""]
 1. e4 e6 2. d3 c5 3. Nf3 Nc6 4. g3 (4. Be2 g6 {4...d5!} 5. O-O Bg7 6. c3 Nge7 7. Be3 d6 8. d4) 4... g6 5. Bg2 Bg7 6. O-O Nge7 7. c3 d6 8. Re1 e5 9. a3 O-O 10. b4 a6 11. Be3 b6 12. Nbd2 h6 13. Rb1 Be6 14. Qc2 *
```

I am not a big fan of the King's Indian Attack. Frankly, your opponent's response, which I like a lot, with an early g6 tends to really blunt the main k-side attacking premise that makes this opening fun for white sometimes, and thus, the main reason to play it. The other thing is that in this c5 variation, black always can go for the normal Sicilian "equalizing" move, d5 with little trouble.

The fact is that your second move cedes space to black from a very early stage, so it is hard to believe that you will be able to gain an advantage out of the opening. You might want to hide your intentions a little more too with 2.Nf3, 3.g3, and only then, play d3 before showing your hand. He might not play a line with g6.

As to what to do, because g6 really makes it hard to attack his king as in the main lines, the line I gave sets you up to play the re1 to d1 and the ra1 to b1 and eventually to play bc. If he opens the b-file, you will try to play on it, and you are probably better placed to use it, or if he opens the d-file, you can play for d4. If you really do not have play on the k-side, you have to look at the center and q-side.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with direct `9.d4`? If `9...Bg4, 10.d5`

Comment: @Akavall It appears to drop a pawn. Black can just keep taking...it is over-defended by the Bg7 after the traded. 9.d4 ed 10.cd Nd4 11.Nd4 cd and it will be easy to hang onto with Nc6 and even Qb6 if necessary.

Comment: Yes, right. Thank You.